# ffmpeg two audio, one video in output

Tags: php, audio, video, ffmpeg

Hi all I just installed ffmpeg and I'm quite new to it. 
managed to combine/merge audio and video file, but now I want to combine 2 audio files and one video into one output file. 
audio files are: .wav 
video file is: .flv
output is: .flv

currently i have this code, what should I add to it:

`system("$ffmpegpath -i audio1.wav -i audio2.wav -i video1.flv -y output.flv");`

thank you!

Comment: do you get the solution??

Comment: hi, to be honest this is a pretty old issue and we didn't get any help. we managed to make it work somehow, but surely not with 2 audio files combined. 1 video + 1 audio. I'll try to get a hold of the files and get back to you.

Comment: Okay Thanks.. I am trying it more if I am able to get the solution I will share my answer.

Comment: check out my answer and let me know if it works, maybe I can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the project and this is my solution to it:

```
<?php
    $ffmpegpath = "ffmpeg.exe"; /////ffmpeg.exe path, I have it in the same folder
    $videoFile = "videoplayback.flv";
    $audioFile = "comment.wav";
    $targetVideo = "output.flv";

    //
    system("$ffmpegpath -i $audioFile -i $videoFile -y $targetVideo");
?>
```

let me know if it helps!

Comment: I am trying to develop for android 2 audio files which merge into one. Can you tell me whats the command for the ffmeg library?

Comment: possible to find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498539/how-to-overlay-two-audio-files-using-ffmpeg

or read here:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20(join,%20merge)%20media%20files

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the option -map. Read this link, [How to encode multi audio streams with different options at the same time with ffmpeg](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1943934)

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i merged-vobs.mpeg -map 0:0 -s 640x368 -f ogg -vcodec libtheora -r 25 -b:v 1200k -metadata:s:v:0 title= "Video Title" -acodec libvorbis -ar 48000 -map 0:1 -ac:a:0 6 -b:a:0 192k -metadata:s:a:0 title="Track1 Title" -map 0:4 -ac:a:1 2 -b:a:1 96k -metadata:s:a:1 title="Track2 Title" -async 1 -pass 2 -passlogfile "outputlog" "output.ogv"
```

Comment: Thank you @Álvaro! I will give it a try and get back here.

Comment: is this work?? I am trying using this but bnot works: FFMPEG command work fine in the log but didt find the result any hekp ffmpeg -i file1.mp3 -i file2.mp3 mix.mp4 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -newaudio

Answer (score 0):

```
 ffmpeg -i file1.mp3 -i file2.mp3 mix.mp4 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -newaudio
```